# What is the formula to calculate the distance covered in a specific time (e.g 3rd second, 4th sec...) by a contantly accelarated body?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

consider the following question:
The distance covered by a freely falling body in 2nd second of its journey is?
**solution**:
**distance covered is 1st second is**:
S1=Vit + 1/2gt^2...**put values**
S=5m
**Distance covered in 2nd second is**:
S2=Vit + 1/2gt^2...**put Vi=10m/s^2...(this value is calculated from 1st equation of motion)** by putting all values we get, 
S=15m...hence (S2=3S1)
**i would like a single equation which solves this stuff! so how to derive a single equation instead of using two equation of motions?**

Comment: You can use [Galileo's law of odd numbers](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/482822/123208).

Answer (score 1):

I hope that the following answer helps.

Let the distance covered in $n$ seconds be $S_n$ and distance covered in $n-1$ seconds be $S_{n-1}$.
Then considering $1D$ motion,

$S_n = u_0n + \frac{an^2}{2}$

$S_{n-1} = u_0(n-1) + \frac{a(n-1)^2}{2}$

$S_{n} - S_{n-1} = u_0(n) + \frac{an^2}{2} - u_0(n-1) - \frac{a(n-1)^2}{2}$

Hence,

**$$S_{n^{th} second} = u_0 + \frac{a(2n-1)}{2}$$**

where $a$ is the acceleration and $u_0$ is the initial velocity.

Comment: wow! Bundle of thanks! i really appreciated it because this is of great help in mcqs in order to save time! i spent 8 hours to derive this equation but in vain! thanks once again!

Comment: Glad to help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is somewhat unclear, so I will answer what I understood. 
You wish to find the position at any time of a freely falling object.

In order to do that, you must find the position as a function of time. Now, the motion will depend on the following variables. The initial position or height, h, the initial velocity, $v_0$ and the acceleration a. Thus the general formula is 
$$y(t) = h +v_0t +\frac{at^2}{2}$$
Note that in free fall the acceleration a is just the acceleration of gravity g=-9.8m/s^2

This should be the general formula that you are looking for. I recommend you to check out books such as Serway physics for scientists an engineers if you wish to know more