# Dimensionally inconsistent!

Tags: kinematics, units, dimensional-analysis

This equation doesn't seem to be correct. Dimensionally inconsistent, in fact! How then, is it established? $$s_{t}=v_{0}+\frac{1}{2}a(2t-1)$$ (In case you don't know, this is the equation used to measure displacement in $t^{th}$ second.)

Comment: The right side needs to be multiplied by $\Delta t=1$ second. It was presumably omitted because “it’s just 1”, but this is a very confusing thing to do.

Comment: And the $-1$ is really $-\Delta t$.

Comment: Are you actually using a textbook that writes equations like this?

Comment: ... Yep. That's a third world country physics textbook for you. Pretty ‘commercial’, and doesn't focus on conceptual understanding at all. Seriously tho, to average students here, Physics = Math.

Comment: So do you understand now how to get the formula by taking the difference of the displacement at time $t$ and at time $t-\Delta t$, using formulas for constant acceleration?

Comment: Yes. Thanks for the generous support! I just had to take a close look tho, I now noticed that it's a silly question.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/482822/galileos-law-of-odd-numbers I'm sad to hear that you have to use a textbook like that. :~(

Comment: @PM2Ring Nothing you can do to help. Unless, you have some O/A-level physics book(s) to suggest.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't been following physics textbook trends, my school years were a few decades ago. However, one of our prominent members, Ben Crowell, has made several of his textbooks available online for free. See his site, http://www.lightandmatter.com

Comment: Thank you! I'll check it out!